# Any problem with cutting a hole through one section of attic to another attic? for ventilation

Tags: roof, attic, ventilation

I have an attic that has no vent and another attic (I assume) that has a vent on the outside of the house, a "gable vent" I think is the correct term.

I want the hot air to get out of attic #1 (where I can feel it is quite hot), and be able to rise out of there in the summer through the existing vent.

It seems like going through whatever is between the attic and the other attic (maybe it is an old roof and the new section was built on top? or maybe it is just wall of some sort, it looks slanted) should be a no-brainer and change virtually nothing about the house, other than the change I do want (ventilation).  Tell me if I'm missing anything?  Thanks.

(I know I need to avoid cutting through a support such as a stud.)

Comment: If a single family home it was probably an addition and I have cut holes similar to what you plan on just make sure you won’t be changing the structure,  you should have access to both sides and should be able to open it up without taking structural lumber out.

Comment: Thanks.  I realize I also need vents under the eves, but this is a stop-gap to get some of the heat out.

I can see where the old roof slope was, steeper than the new one.  I drilled a few test holes, nothing exploded or collapsed.

Comment: attic partitions can slow fire spread, make sure your insurance is cool with making risk-increasing modifications.

Comment: I would suggest you talk to your building inspector, that may be a fire wall and illegal to defeat the purpose of it. It could also affect your insurance coverage, you need to check with them as dandavis suggested.

Comment: Garage attic must be “fire separated” from rest of house and rest of house attic.

Comment: This is not true where I live in my part of the US. Garage lid and walls adjoining living space must have 1 hour fire rating but not garage attic to house attic.

Comment: @LeeSam - yet again, another point that would be helped with info. on OP's location.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer here, but I think you're overestimating the benefit of doing so. You likely won't get enough airflow to make much difference. You should look into installing proper ridge and soffit vents throughout.